# Dataflow - Error while assigning Custom Timestamp

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to assign a custom timestamp and check how the allowed lateness works. The below code works fine when I run it in interactive() runner but when I switch to dataflowrunner() It starts throwing error.I noticed  the error is from

```
Map(lambda x: window.TimestampedValue(x, x["timestamp"]))
```

Input data is same in both the cases i.e {'name': 'rou', 'score': 50,'timestamp':1618295060} . In dataflow UI only I see no of errors but nowhere I could see the error details.I have included logging as well as exception. I a not sure why errors are not logged.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZOGp.png)

```
class BuildRecordFn(beam.DoFn):
def __init__(self):
    super(BuildRecordFn, self).__init__()

def process(self, s,  window=beam.DoFn.WindowParam):
    #window_start = window.start.to_utc_datetime()
    window_end = window.end.to_utc_datetime()
    return [dict(name=s[0],score=s[1], timestamp=str(window_end))]
windowed_words = (words_source 
              | "read" >> 
               beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic="projects/{}/topics/beambasics".format(project))
              |"To Dict" >> beam.Map(json.loads)
              |"with timestamp">>  Map(lambda x: window.TimestampedValue(x, x["timestamp"]))
              |"Map" >>Map(lambda x : (x['name'],x['score']))
              | "window" >> beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(60),
                                            #trigger=Repeatedly(AfterProcessingTime(1 * 10)),
                  # accumulation_mode=AccumulationMode.ACCUMULATING,                         
             allowed_lateness=Duration(seconds=1*50))
             |"Group">> CombinePerKey(sum) 
             |"convert to dict">> ParDo(BuildRecordFn())
             |"Write To BigQuery" >> WriteToBigQuery(table=table, schema=schema,
                              create_disposition=BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                              write_disposition=BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND) 
             )
```

Comment: at first glance, it looks you are sending the timestamp parameter as string, I think it should be integer / float. Also, you can see the logs better directly going to Cloud Logging or clicking on the step itself.

Comment: hm this looks like a bug. Have you tried opening the logs explorer to find any error-looking logs? Have you looked at worker logs?